# All predictions are the same for neuralnet method in caret library

Tags: r, r-caret

The neural network model trained using the train() method of the Caret library produces the exact same prediction value for the test data set. Also, using the same tuning parameters train() function takes a whole lot longer than using neuralnet() directly. The predictors are range normalized to (0, 1).

The following code works fast and gives reasonable results, i.e., predictions are not all the same for the test data.

```
neuralnet(MEDV ~ . , bh.norm.tr, linear.output = TRUE, hidden = 3)
```

However, when I use Caret with the same parameters:

```
layer.grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = 3, layer2 = 0, layer3 = 0)
nnCtrl <- trainControl(method = 'none')
bh.MEDV.cv.nn <- train(MEDV ~ . , data = bh.norm.tr,
                    method = "neuralnet", 
                    trControl = nnCtrl,
                    tuneGrid = layer.grid)
```

This code takes way too long, like 10+ minutes to run and gives somewhat worse results than using neuralnet() directly.

More confusing still to me is, if I use a slightly more complex network, like:

```
layer.grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = 3, layer2 = 2, layer3 = 0)
nnCtrl <- trainControl(method = 'cv')
```

then, all the predictions of the validate data are exactly the same number.

All predictors are range normalized.  I also used learningrate = .01 parameter in the train() and that did not make any difference.

I am totally lost at this point. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

```
nnCtrl <- trainControl(method = 'none')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.